# Roots of $f(x) = x^p - x - a$ in a field with characteristic $p > 0$

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, finite-fields

I am working on the following problem:

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $p > 0$. Let $f(x) = x^p - x - a$ with any element $a \in k$. Suppose that $f(x)$ has a root in $k$. Show that $f(x)$ has exactly $p$ roots in $k$.

First, I considered the field $\mathbb{F}_p$ , which is a field with characteristic $p$. Let $\alpha$ be a root of $f(x) = x^p - x - a$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$. Then $\alpha + 1$ is a root of $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$, since $f(\alpha + 1) = (\alpha + 1)^p - (\alpha + 1) - a = \alpha^p + 1^p - \alpha - 1 - a = \alpha^p - \alpha - a = 0$. If we continue this inductively $p$ times, we find that $\alpha + \beta$ ($1 \leq \beta \leq p$) are all roots of $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$. Thus, every element of $\mathbb{F}_p$ is a root of $f(x)$, giving exactly $p$ roots in $\mathbb{F}_p$ as desired.

Now, I'm struggling with generalizing this to the field $GF(p^n)$, $n > 1$, since this is also a field of characteristic $p$. The same strategy above will show that one can obtain $p$ roots of $f(x)$ in this field -- but how can I show that there are no more roots beyond those $p$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: $f$ has degree $p$, and so cannot have more than $p$ zeroes in any field.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I must be too tired. Thanks a lot. (=

Comment: I am troubled by your proof in the first place since if $x^p-x-a=0\mod{}p$ then since every element has order $p$ that would imply $a=0\mod{}p$ and thus you only solved $x^p-x=0\mod{}p$. You also didn’t use induction at all, you only “showed” that if $a$ satisfies the equation so does $a+1$ but $a$ is specific and in fact $a^p-2a\ne{}0$. The thing is if $a$ isn’t $0$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$ you have no solutions actually.

Comment: What I want to say is that in $\mathbb{F}_p$ if your polynomial has a root then $a=0$ and every element indeed satisfies the equation.

Comment: I think you should give up the approach of looking first at $\Bbb F_p$ and then larger finite fields, since after all the question sone’t say anything about your constant field being finite. You should be able to do this whole thing without consideration of the size of $k$.